# Xml return in web service WSDL to php

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to bring data from a WSDL service done in c # - .asmx , in php

I currently use this code to get the data from the web service but I have many exits wrong

to make this call I get this output

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/SVPlanificacion/Servicios/servArticulo.asmx?WSDL", array('trace' => FALSE));

    $response = $client->ArticuloCategoria();

echo var_dump($response);
```

**output 1**

> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["ArticuloCategoriaResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["any"]=> string(4594) "10AGUA CALIENTEAGUA CALIENTEtrue9AGUA FRIAAGUA FRIAtrue110AGUAS NEGRASAGUAS NEGRAStrue130CABLEStrue4CUARTO 1/4CUARTO 1/4true2CUÑETECUÑETEtrue3GALONGALONtrue7GALON SILICONGALON SILICONtrue6GARRAFAGARRAFAtrue140LIJAtrue5LITROLITROtrue10N/AN/Atrue8POTE PEQPOTE PEQtrue120TABLEROStrue" } }

trying to achieve to get this out but not what I want quer

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/SVPlanificacion/Servicios/servArticulo.asmx?WSDL");

echo $client->ArticuloCategoria()->ArticuloCategoriaResult->any;
```

**output 2**

> 10AGUA CALIENTEAGUA CALIENTEtrue9AGUA FRIAAGUA FRIAtrue110AGUAS NEGRASAGUAS NEGRAStrue130CABLEStrue4CUARTO 1/4CUARTO 1/4true2CUÑETECUÑETEtrue3GALONGALONtrue7GALON SILICONGALON SILICONtrue6GARRAFAGARRAFAtrue140LIJAtrue5LITROLITROtrue10N/AN/Atrue8POTE PEQPOTE PEQtrue120TABLEROStrue

but there remains a TRUE concatenated to all data and does not come the header or the name of each column which would IdArticuloCategoria , Name , Description , for each data ...

I would like a similar output to an xml which is the same format that gives the web service but can not find way to generate , thanks for the help they can provide me ... !

regards